# Is Modular Entropy Multiplication really a new form of entropy?

Tags: circuit-analysis, random-number

I have come across Modular Entropy Multiplication (MEM) on GitHub. It's used as an entropy source for a hardware true random number generator called [REDOUBLER](https://github.com/alwynallan/redoubler). I've never seen such a circuit. Ye olde avalanche diodes are common enough, but this seems new...

[image: mem circuit]

I've *reduced* this circuit to a simpler layout than seen in [other](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waywardgeek/infnoise/master/images/infnoise.png) parts of the Interweb:-

[image: infini circuit]

As previously, it works by alternately clocking the analogue switch inputs SW1EN and SW2EN, and digitised entropy appears at the comparator outputs, COMP1 and COMP2. For information, it's two units that (I think) can operate independently if you just close the feedback loop around one set of sample and hold components.

[image: traces]

The designer advertises about 7.9 bits/byte of entropy from the circuit, without any further whitening. That's a purity of 98.8%, which seems like very good stuff.

A. Is this really a new form of entropy within circuits, as it's a very uncommon technique?

B. Is there any reason to suspect that COMP1 output would be highly correlated to COMP2 output?

Answer (score 2):

By doubling the voltage in every step, this circuit essentially amplifies the small amount of noise present in all components.

However, there is no proof of how much of the output is a result of unpredictable noise, as opposed to predictable (in theory) imperfections of the components. So I would treat the claim of 7.9 bits of entropy as unfounded.

The related [Inifinite Noise](https://github.com/waywardgeek/infnoise) project does such an analysis (including an explanation where the noise comes from), and claims about 6.9 bits of entropy per byte.

Comment: So you believe that it's a simple noise amplifier?  I couldn't understand the contribution of the comparators' feedback. I thought that it may be some form of ring oscillator /Chau circuit.

Comment: It's not quite *simple*. The op amp multiplies the voltage by about 2; the comparator shifts the voltage down by the supply voltage if it would overflow otherwise.